# SCIM 2.0 and external AD groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, scim, scim2

We implemented SCIM for an enterprise app and it is working fine.  We were told that we could add external AD groups to allow our partners users to be able to access the app as well.  For example, Company A (us) uses Azure AD and wants to add a specific AD group from Company B (different network/domain) to be provisioned in the app.  I was told this was possible, but I can't find documentation on setup of external groups.

I may have the terminology wrong which is probably not helping.

Any directions to documentation or examples would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Groups can only be provisioned/assigned to an application if they are managed in the same Azure AD tenant as the application that is configured to do provisioning. You can create a group in your Azure AD tenant and populate it with external/guest users as members - in that case, the group will be managed by your organization's tenant, but the members will be guests homed in another tenant.